# Ubuntu 16.04 logout 15 seconds after logging in

Tags: login, reboot

New here, so please be gentle...

Just picked up a new laptop with 16.04 pre-installed. Ran apt-get dist-update, which took a while, and restarted the computer. Now when I login, however, it opens for 15seconds and then it returns to the login screen. I can login as a Guest User just fine, but am unable to do anything from there. Also, when I try to use C-Alt-F1, nothing happens. Not sure how to fix this. Thanks!

EDIT: So now when I login it directly kicks me back to the login screen. I can still login as a Guest, but again, even from the terminal there i can't access my regular user. Since this is brand new, I'm thinking about simply doing a reinstall. Anything special I need? I should be able to download it on another computer, transfer the file to a USB drive, then install it from there, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu.
Now, this response from a related question could help.

Similar problem happened to my friend because somehow he corrupted the .Xautority file.

Log into a tty (Control+Alt+F6) and after typing your username and password:

`sudo rm -v .Xauthority`

.Xauthority file can be found in /home/, which is where the terminal's default working path also usually is. If you use a tty to sign in as one user to delete another's .Xauthority file, make sure you'vecd'd to the right directory first.

Then restart lightdm with:

`sudo service lightdm restart`

The system will recreate the .Xautority file. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, I can't access a tty. I try (Cnt+Alt+F6) and nothing happens. I can get a terminal when I login, but as I mention, I only have 15 seconds before it logs me back out!

Comment: Actually, I think I completed the command you gave me, because now it doesn't log in at all. It immediately loops back to the login screen.